# Redirect to another page by Clicking Image

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Currently, I am developing a WordPress site. I need to link a page using the image (onclick event => redirect to another page. However, it has already linked using a text over the image.

```
<div class="img-one">
    <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1303" src="image-source" alt="" width="850" height="1250" />
    <div class="adventure-link">
        <a href="page-link">Topic</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since I need to keep the text link> Kindly help me to link the image to the destination page. (Text Box has used to insert image and link.

Comment: You can simply add the image in anchor tag <a href="//Page Link"><img src="//Image Path"></a>

Comment: @PanchalKrupal Hi the way you saying is not working. I tried it before posting this question. Thanks

Comment: So, you want to go to another page on the image click?

Comment: @PanchalKrupal Yeah. Cut I need to keep the text as well

Comment: Hi. Please check the below-posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use an a tag as the parent of img tag and put attribute target=blank for a

```
<div class="img-one">
  <a href="link" target="blank">
    <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1303" src="image-source" alt="" width="850" height="1250" />
  </a>
```

then it doesn't need onclick function

Answer (score 0):

you can add the onclick attribute to the image like this:

```
<img onclick="window.location.href='http://example.com'" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1303" src="image-source" alt="" width="850" height="1250" />
```

Or just wrap the image in another href:

```
<a href="http://example.com"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1303" src="image-source" alt="" width="850" height="1250" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
<img src="//Image Path" onclick="location.href = '//Page you want to go';" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

Comment: => thanks for the response. Found a way. Text also need to write on a seperate class.

Answer (score 0):

You can Just add an onclick event to the image:

```js
 document.getElementById("redirectimg").onclick = function () {
             window.location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com";
        };
```

```html
<div class="img-one">
    
    <img id="redirectimg" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1303" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sample-stamp-grunge-texture-vector-260nw-1389188336.jpg" alt="" width="850" height="1250" />
    <div class="adventure-link"><a href="page-link">Topic</a></div>
    </div>
```

But you should add id in img tag.

OR you can try like this :

```html
  <div class="img-one">
    
    <img id="redirectimg" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1303" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sample-stamp-grunge-texture-vector-260nw-1389188336.jpg" alt="" width="850" height="1250" onClick="window.location='https://stackoverflow.com/';"  />
    <div class="adventure-link"><a href="page-link">Topic</a></div>
    </div>
```